# Preserving call when notification arrives

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, callkit

I've voice call feature which I've implemented using Twilio and callkit. User is in a call and a notification for the app arrives, user clicks on this notification which takes user to a view linked to this notification. When user taps on this notification call disconnects.

How do I stop call being disconnected in this scenario?

It works in WhatsApp. You can be connected with another user on voice/video. You can receive notification, tap on it, navigate away to another view, chat with users and phone/video call remains connected.

So I'm assuming it's possible. I'm not just sure how to implement it. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would want to hold the first call while switching to the second one. So you will have to implement `provider(performSetHeldCallAction:)` and in your `CXCallUpdate` you should set `update.supportsHolding = true`. This way, the first call will remain connected and held while the user switches over to a second call which then becomes the active call.